# How can I fit video thumbnail in box?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Currently, I'm making a system that can control home electrical equipment on the web.
When I set camera images, I want to fit the image well in the container, but it is displayed no fit in box.

[image]

How can I fit video thumbnail in box?

React.js

```
<div className="discover_device col-4">
    <div className="box">
    <ReactPlayer
        className="camera_video_discover"
        url={'xxx.com'}
        controls={false}
        playing
        muted
        config={{
            file: {
                hlsOptions: {
                    xhrSetup: (xhr) => {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`);
                        },
                },
            },
        }} 
        />
    <div className="discover_item_room_name_entity_id">
        <p className="discover_item_room_name_carmera">Room Name</p>
        <p className="discover_item_entity_id_camera">Camear Name</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  background:#1E3E75; 
  padding:15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 300px;
}


.discover_item_room_name_entity_id {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20;
  left: 100;
}

.discover_item_entity_id_camera {
  position: absolute;
}

.box .camera_video_discover {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

I changed the code below but it does not cover box all...

[image]

```
.box .camera_video_discover {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you typo at this code? because you don't have a class .box_discover_camera

```
.box_dicover_camera .camera_video_discover {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed and I fix .box_dicover_camera to .box now but still same result...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work since I don't know what kind of HTML element `ReactPlayer` is, but maybe adding `display: block` to `.camera_video_discover` and `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` class might do the trick.

```
.box .camera_video_discover {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. ReactPlaer is kind of Video. Those code makes the video thumbnail fits in box but not cover all box. Please take a look added photo.

Comment: thanks but same result...

Comment: hmm not sure, it's really hard when there is no reproducible codes in the question, i'm really not sure if <ReactPlayer> is a <video> element or it's something more complex than that (e.g. a <video> wrapped inside another element). You should inspect element it and see what's the elements hierarchy is